# Django: PostgreSQL Graph Search

Tags: python, django, postgresql, graph

Is there any simple way to use PostgreSQL's [graph search functionality](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/postgresql-graph-search-practices---10-billion-scale-graph-with-millisecond-response_595039)  with Django's Querysets?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, but there's no reason why you couldn't use those recipes with the [raw SQL escape hatches](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly), then use the regular QuerySet functionality to retrieve the objects according to graph results.

(With sufficient finagling, you might be able to use [`.raw()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries) too.)

Comment: Any sense of how this performs versus a real graph database? I'm relatively new to graph search.

Comment: In general, Postgresql is pretty performant. The only way to really find out is to benchmark both – but if you already have Postgresql in production, not having to set up a separate graph database is a boon :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is about a year old, but if you (or anyone else) are still looking for graph functionality with Django and PostgreSQL, check out [django-postgresql-dag](https://pypi.org/project/django-postgresql-dag/)

It's specific to Directed Acyclic Graphs, but regularly improved and updated.